# Ubuntu Installer Freezing Up But Allows Mouse Movement

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, mate

When I try to install Ubuntu Mate on my system (a Dell 7567) I can load the live USB, and it works fine for a few seconds, but after a few seconds the system freezes up, however the mouse can move about, but I cannot interact with anything. I've tried using an external mouse, and the exhibits the same symptoms. 
I have a Nvidia GTX 1050 in this laptop, and I read that possibly that is the cause of it, but I can't even get to a terminal to switch to the integrated graphics, as it only lasts about a second or two before freezing.

My specs are:

i5-7300HQ

16GB RAM

Nvidia GTX 1050

Attempting to Dual boot with windows 10

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to boot with `nomodeset` and then install the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia that worked! Can you add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that when a USB OS doesn't work well, it's usually because it wasn't made well enough. That could either be cause the USB didn't download right, or the graphical USB makers, both Windows, Mac and Linux, didn't write the USB right and this is often the case when USB's fail, and they fail often. You'll probably just have to make another USB until you get a semi-workable USB from a graphical maker in Windows or Mac if you don't have a linux to do it.. What a pain, ehh..

I've found that the best system; if you can get at least a semi-workable USB, is to load the USB and use:

from the terminal:

1. shred -vfz /dev/sd_ (whatever the last letter of your USB is)
2. then open Gparted and add a partition table to the USB and
3. Restart the computer, download the ISO and use the terminal command: sudo dd if=ubuntu_iso of=/dev/sd_ (whatever your usb letter is)

DD has never let me down. Once you get a perfect USB made, then use that to make your new computer.. good luck